# left join between different tables in DBT

Tags: sql, etl, dbt

I am working on a use case to convert an ETL process (Abinitio graph) to DBT SQL.

The ETL process joins one table with multiple other tables using left join and produce the final output. For eg , T1 is the main table (Driving table) and other tables are A , B , C , D , E. T1 is linked with all the other tables , but A , B ,C , D , E are not related.

The ETL process performs left join between T1 & other tables on different columns and produce the final output. ETL process uses lookup concept to execute this.

When I am trying to convert that into DBT SQL , I can think of below options -

Option 1:
Left Join T1 with A and put that in a separate model and keep the primary column of T1 , key columns for the join & fetched columns from A. This will be stored in a table or view.

Perform the same thing for all tables.

In the final model , perform inner join with all these tables and fetch required columns from individual table.

PROS : better lineage view
CONS : Each table will be joined separately, and total data volume would be high.

Option 2 :
Write a big SQL which performs all join in a single query and use the final output.
PROS : Might be quicker than option 1 and less coding.
CONS : Data lineage view won't be great as everything will be in a single model.

Any other approaches ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is the logical way to do this, lineage will be the same either way as dbt only tracks lineage between models, not columns. However Option 1 is more work to create and maintain over time.

There are some scenarios where something like Option 1 may work better e.g. the size of the tables means that a statement joining all of them in one query does complete in a reasonable time (or at all). Breaking it into multiple smaller queries might be your only option in that case.
Or if there are way more than the five or six tables in your example then you might want to simplify things by having a few smaller sets of joins to intermediate tables before joining them all in a final table.

However if it's possible to put all the logic in one model then that's probably the best choice.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, for the details. But I don't think Option 2 will provide similar lineage as option1 . As you have correctly mentioned that DBT builds the lineage between models , in this case if I put everything under a single model with a very big SQL - then there won't be any lineage. on the other hand, if I provide joined values in different model for each join and then combine that in the final join - it will be easier to view the lineage and identify which model holds what kind of joining condition & tracking columns from target to source would be much easier.

Comment: With option 1 you will artificially create more layers in the model lineage but they will tell you nothing that the lineage resulting from option 2 would create - you will still ultimately be joining same tables together in the same way, but in multiple stages instead of one. If you feel like this will be easier for you to understand then it may be the right option for you - multiple simpler models are easier to support in some ways.

Comment: The specific request for converting to DBT has the main goal of making things more simpler by distributing into multiple smaller modules / models . Will go for that approach. Thanks Nathan for the help.